# PHP: oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I want to call a oracle function with PHP but I get the error:

> oci_execute(): ORA-01008: not all variables bound

The parameter:

```
:pDATDEB = 21102019 (String)
:pDATFIN = 27102019 (String)
:pCURSEUR = (is an OUT Parameter) (Cursor)
```

The code:

```
$sql = "BEGIN :result := sceref.PACK_W_PLANNING.PLANNING_MISSIONS(:pDATDEB, :pDATFIN, :pCURSEUR); END;";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

// bind the first and last name variables
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':pDATDEB', $startDate);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':pDATFIN', $endDate);

// bind the ref cursor
$refcur = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':result', $refcur, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);

// execute the statement
oci_execute($stmt);

// treat the ref cursor as a statement resource
oci_execute($refcur, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_fetch_all($refcur, $data, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

// return the results
return ($data);
```

It works on SQL (here is an image):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function has three parameters and return a value. the value that your function return is nor a cursor it is a float!

you are trying to bound only to parameter and  combine a float with a cursor

the `:result` is not the cursor. your cursor is `:pCURSEUR`.
so it should looks like:

```
$curs = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":pCURSEUR", $curs, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":result", $result);
```

i did not tst it, but it should show you the way